# C++ : return an object that can be of a special derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Sorry for the length, but I can't figure out how to ask this question without an introduction.

Let's imagine to have to implement a "number" (an object of `class CNum`) that could be a (signed) integer (∈ℤ) or a rational number (∈ℚ).
Imagine there is a member function `prn` to print the number. Of course we want to print integers and rational numbers in different way.

A typical "*old style*" (C/ish) implementation could be like:

```
class CNum
{
 public:
  char type; // In this example, 'Q' or 'Z'.
  [...]
  char *prn(char *s)
   {
    if(type=='Z') sprintf(s,"something...."); else
    if(type=='Q') sprintf(s,"something else ...");
    return s;
   }
  [...]
};
```

More "*modern*" (C++/ish) approachs tend to use derived classes and virtual functions.
So I'll write something like:

```
class CNum
{
 public:
  [...]
  virtual char *prn(char *s) {....};
};

class ZZ : public CNum
{
  long int n; // n is the value.
  // implementation for integers, with proper prn()
};

class QQ : public CNum
{
  long int a; unsigned long int b; // a/b is the value.
  // implementation for rationals, with proper prn()
};
```

...and it seems much better (doesn't it?).

OK... now, I need the code to divide an integer by another one.
In general, the ratio between two integers is a rational, so I would write:

```
QQ operator / (ZZ &x, ZZ &y)
{
 QQ R;
 long int j;

 if(y.n<0) {R.a=-x.n; R.b=-y.n;}
 else      {R.a= x.n; R.b= y.n;}
 for(j=2; j<=abs(R.a) && j<=R.b; j++) while(!(R.a%j) && !(R.b%j)) {R.a/=j; R.b/=j;}
 if(R.b==1) ; // (it's a whole number, stored as rational)(sorry...)
 return R;
}
```

The longest line (`for(j...`) is what allows, e.g., to have a result such as 2/3 instead of 2006/3009

So, here comes the actual question: how can I return an object of type `class ZZ` (instead of `class QQ`) in the case `if(R.b==1)`?
It would be trivial in the "*old style*" approach. But this would mean that all the member functions should be an aggregate of `if(type==...){...} else if(type==...){...} else ...` -- not what I would like to maintain.

What would the experts suggest?

(I have sort of found a solution returning a reference to a new object, but it's worst than the problem or it leaks memory)

Also: if someone understood the question (also without knowing the answer): any suggestion for a better title?

Comment: Return some kind of smart pointer?

Answer (score 0):

By SO's advice, avoid answering questions in comments. But I am not providing a complete answer... so this is somewhere inbetween a comment and an answer.

The issue you face is that QQ and ZZ are different objects with different sizes. Notably one of them has an additional member variable (unsigned long int b).

So the operator / cannot return both by value depending on context because they are incompatible. They have different types but also different sizes.

Basically the solution here is type erasure. Essentially you want to make a type, lets say called MyNumber. It is a container which either stores a type MyInteger or MyRational inside it.

This means that every operation done on MyNumber has to have a run-time test to see whether it is storing an instance of MyInteger or MyRational inside it... and then calling the appropriate function to operate on that type.

To implement type erasure you have two basic options:

1. Internally on MyNumber it would store a pointer to either MyInteger or MyRational. This adds an extra layer of indirection and can hit your cache, so for something like a numeric type its probably undesirable.
2. Use Union given all possible representations for MyNumber are known at compile time. This allows them to be stored on the stack and generally speaking allows you to more easily ensure the contained data in a series of MyNumber instances is located close together.

A quick Google search turns up this which has a neat example of type erasure in it:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Erasure

That implementation internally uses a unique_ptr, so its going the allocation route. You might need to look up unions and see how you might use them.

EDIT:

Clearly its been too long since I've done C++! Instead of doing a union, which would be a bunch of stuff that begins to delve into language use you might not be familiar with, you can use std::variant<> as your union.

It would be something like:

```
class MyNumber {
  public:
    MyNumber( MyInteger i )...
    MyNumber( MyRational r )...

    MyNumber operator / (MyNumber const& other) const {
      ... internally use the DivideVisitor struct with std::visit ...
    }

  private:
    struct DivideVisitor {
      ... look up how std::visit works with std::variant ...
      ... and the implementation for this will become clear ...
    };

    std::variant< MyInteger, MyRational > m_internal;
};
```

Comment: As far as I can understand, those are variations on the theme of the "old syle approach", where, in the second case, the behaviour switch logic is in the "visit". Right? Or did I miss something important?

Comment: Well, there are 3 things I think are really important for any solution you're looking at. First you need to wrap this up as a single type which behaves like a value type - so you can write code like you might for a float or other type. Second to act like a basic math type you want the compiler to optimize as such. So if you do a series of operations 
 known at compile time, the solution should enable the compiler to optimize all of that code away if its possible. Lastly data location is important for math types to allow for cache efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about a common problem of any strongly typed language. The problem is, that the function result and, in particular, its type are specified at compile time, but the function parameters are known only at run time. In order to resolve that, you have to use polymorphism.

The solution that you call "old C style" translates to C++ as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<CNum> operator/ (ZZ const& x, ZZ const& y)
{
    //calculate "result = x/y"
    //if rational
    return std::make_unique<QQ>(result);
    //else if whole number
    return std::make_unique<ZZ>(result);
}
```

With this, you return a unique pointer that either points to a rational or a whole number -- which you then can use in your further calculations which also take a `CNum`.

Moreover, if you ever want to know which exactly it is, you could use a `dynamic_cast`:

```
ZZ a;
ZZ b;
auto res = a/b;
if(QQ* d = dynamic_cast<QQ*>(res.get()))
{
     //result is rational
}
else if(ZZ* d = dynamic_cast<ZZ*>(res.get()))
{
     //result is whole
}
```

You should need that rarely, however.

Further, there are other options. For example, you could implement a virtual function `std::string type()` which returns `"Q"` for the derived rational class and `"Z"` for the whole number, thus replacing the `char type` variable in your C-style solution.

Summary: old C-style is hardly ever better than modern C++ style.

Comment: Thanks for this example. It appears to be something similar to what I was trying, but (as I understand) the value returned cannot be used as a number: it would be more like having `int* operator / (int, int)`, i.e. the ratio of two numbers doesn't return the result: it returns a pointer to the result, instead... isn't it?
It would be fine if all the instructions were like `p=n/m;` (→ modify to `p=*(n/m);`)... but it would be a mess for longer expressions like a simple interpolation `y=y0+(x-x0)/(x1-x0)*(y1-y0)`...

Comment: A sad detail is also that `make_unique` is C++14, while I have the "Dev-C++" with C++11, and (up to this morning) I was happy with it. My problem, I know...  The workaround appears to be `#define __cplusplus  201104L`, but I don't know whether it has any disastrous consequences.

Comment: @GGa: regarding the C++11 restriction: `make_unique` is just syntactic sugar for calling the constructor and wrap it in a unique pointer. Without it, you can simply write `std::unique_ptr<ZZ>(new ZZ(1))`, for example.

Comment: @Gga: to the first point: I agree, it's not as simple as using a number. When <you work with (smart) pointers, at a minimum you have to insert the call operator `*` when you do calculations, e.g. `*y=*y0+(*x-*x0)/(*x1-*x0)*(*y1-*y0)` (... although you'd hardly use this exact formula, interpolation, on rationals/whole numbers). For a number, the language provides all the stuff for you. For a pointer, it doesn't, so you have to invent your own definitions, using e.g. operator overloading: `auto operator/(u.p.<ZZ> const& a, u.p.<ZZ> const& b) { ... }` (where u.p.means unique pointer)